# Add wait between loop controllers in jmeter

Tags: loops, timer, jmeter

How to add wait of 30 sec. in between 2 loop controller?

Each loop controller has loop count 10.
Scenario:
1.No. of threads=5
2.For each user, No. of loop controllers=5

- Loop_controller_1(count=10, i.e. 10 HTTP request)
- Wait for 10 sec
- Loop_controller_2(count=10 i.e. 10 HTTP request)
- wait for 10 sec
- Loop_controller_3(count=10 i.e. 10 HTTP request)
- wait for 10 sec
- Loop_controller_4(count=10 i.e. 10 HTTP request)
- wait for 10 sec
- Loop_controller_5(count=10 i.e. 10 HTTP request)
- wait for 10 sec

Please check there is no wait between 10 HTTP request, it must wait after 10 are completed. How to use Jmeter components?

Answer (score 0):

Add [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) between Controllers and choose Pause with 10000 miliseconds

> allows pauses to be included without needing to generate a sample

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve:

1. You can add a 30 seconds wait for each thread (virtual user) **individually** you can add a [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) as a child of the first request in the Loop Controller 2, timers are executed before requests so each thread will wait for the defined amount of time prior to starting the new Loop Controller

   [image]
2. You can configure JMeter to "gather" all threads and tell them to wait for the specified amount of time together by adding a [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler and a [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer/) with number of users to group by equal to the number of threads in your thread group

   [image]