# Jmeter 5.3 - How to loop the scripts with a certain time interval in between each of them

Tags: jmeter

**Jmeter 5.3**

I have 10 scripts under a Thread group and I want to loop them such that each one of them starts exactly after 30 seconds.
Any pointers on how to do this please ?

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64975861/add-wait-between-loop-controllers-in-jmeter/64977153#64977153

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) at the same level as "scripts" (I think you mean [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers)) and configure it to produce a 30000 ms delay

Given:

1. [Timers are executed **before** samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers)
2. Timers obey [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide)

It would be sufficient to add a single Constant Timer to implement the 30 seconds delay between the requests:

[image]